# css resolutions media queries - **single page site**

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, resolution

Really having a hard time with this. Hope someone sticks around to help me figure this out.

Goal: use CSS to adjust my on-screen elements to make my site look good on all resolutions for desktops and laptops. I need to include both width AND height, because it's a single-page site, meant to fit the viewport only (no scrolling down) and the elements need to be appropriately placed on the screen.

I'm using 8 "swaths" of resolutions to try to account for all viewport resolutions a user may drag their window to. Here is a visual representation I drew. Note that the sections are numbered to the same numbers as the CSS sections: http://i1318.photobucket.com/albums/t654/thekevinbanas/pics%20yo/CSSresolutionswaths_zps41ee8742.jpg

My code is as follows. I labeled a header in each of them a different color so I can see which code is being employed. Essentially I should be able to drag my viewport to be able to change the header's color to all 8, right?

```
/* 1 */
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) and (max-height:768px) {
  (green)
}

/* 2 */
@media screen and (min-width:1025px) and (max-width:1152px) and (min-height:769px) and (max-height:864px) {
  (white)
}

/* 3 */
@media screen and (min-width:1153px) and (max-width:1280px) and (max-height:800px) {
  (black)
}

/* 4 */
@media screen and (min-width:1153px) and (max-width:1280px) and (min-height:801px) and (max-height:960px) {
  (blue)
}

/* 5 */
@media screen and (max-width:1152px) and (min-height:865px) and (max-height:960px) {
  (yellow)
}

/* 6 */
@media screen and (min-height: 961px) and (max-width:1280px) {
  (orange)
}

/* 7 */
@media screen and (min-width:1281px) and (min-height:900px) {
  (gray)
}

/* 8 */
@media screen and (min-width:1281px) and (max-height:899px) {
  (aqua)
}
```

Results: The only colors my header changes to, no matter what size I drag the viewport to are aqua, green, and black (as well as a phantom area between black and green, where no code is being employed).

I tried changing the code to @media only screen rather than @media screen, and min/max-device-width/height rather than min/max-width/height (for all 8 sections)...but then only the code with the gray header gets employed. I'm out of ideas.

Can someone explain what's going on? And how to fix my code to do what I want?

Comment: Not doing phone or tablets? Being a responsive website and all...

Comment: I def want to do phone and tablets. But that will be trickier with this site than with most sites I fear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser may be matching multiple declarations. It will use the last one it matches so change the order. Start with the smallest.

```
//default
@media only screen {
    ...
}
//640 x 480
@media only screen and (max-width:640px) and (max-height:480px) {
    ...
}
//1024 x 768
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) and (max-height:768px) {
    ...
}
//1152 x 864
@media only screen and (max-width:1152px) and (max-height:864px) {
    ...
}
//1152 x 960
@media only screen and (max-width:1152px) and (max-height:960px) {
    ...
}
//1280 x 800
@media only screen and (max-width:1280px) and (max-height:800px) {
    ...
}
//1280 x 960
@media only screen and (max-width:1280px) and (max-height:960px) {
    ...
}
//1280 x 960+
@media only screen and (max-width:1280px) and (min-height:961px) {
    ...
}
//1280+ x 899
@media only screen and (min-width:1281px) and (max-height:899px) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: somewhat right, it seems. if it takes only the last one that works, you should start with biggest sizes and work down. thanks for the answer though, it was helpful

Comment: you can add !important too behind your css. For exemple :                   height: 280px !important;